# How to create a button in Dash to exclude values from a series

Tags: python, pandas, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I wrote a code in python that plots some points from a dataframe on a scatter plot using Dash with Plotly. Additionally, I created a callback that allows me to use the LassoSelector tool to select points that I want to remove from the dataframe to recalculate the series without them. The problem is that when I try to remove a point at position X and then one at position X+1, it gives an index error.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'y': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
})

scatter = go.Scatter(
    x = df['x'],
    y = df['y'],
    mode = 'markers'
)

layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'Grafico Teste',
    xaxis = {'title': 'Eixo X'},
    yaxis = {'title': 'Eixo Y'}
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[scatter], layout=layout)

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Grafico de Dispersão'),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='scatter-graph',
        figure=fig
    ),
    html.Div(id='selected-points')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('selected-points', 'children'),
    [Input('scatter-graph', 'selectedData')]
)
def update_selected_points(selectedData):
    if selectedData is None:
        return 'Nenhum ponto foi selecionado'
    else:
        indices = [point['pointIndex'] for point in selectedData['points']]
        selected_points = df.iloc[indices]
        return f'Pontos selecionados: {selected_points.to_dict("records")}'

app.layout.children.append(html.Div([
    html.Button('Excluir pontos selecionados', id='delete-selected-points'),
]))

# Definindo um novo callback para atualizar o gráfico excluindo os pontos selecionados
@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('scatter-graph', 'selectedData')],
    [State('scatter-graph', 'figure')]
)
def delete_selected_points(selectedData, fig):
    if selectedData is not None:
        indices = [point['pointIndex'] for point in selectedData['points']]
        valid_indices = [index for index in indices if index >= 0 and index < len(df)]
        if len(valid_indices) > 0:
            df.drop(valid_indices, inplace=True)
            new_fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], mode='markers')])
            new_fig.update_layout(title='Grafico Teste', xaxis_title='Eixo X', yaxis_title='Eixo Y')
            return new_fig
    return fig


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I would like to be able to remove any points using the LassoSelector without encountering errors due to the order in which I remove the points.

Answer (score 2):

The figure is (re)created with data for x and y but these values are (re)indexed regardless of the dataframe indices (with `go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'])` plotly has no knowledge of the original indexing), so you need to [reset the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) of the dataframe as well for the point indices to keep matching.

Also, I think you might want to make the delete callback triggered by the delete button and grab the current selection via a `State()`.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('delete-selected-points', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('scatter-graph', 'selectedData'), State('scatter-graph', 'figure')],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def delete_selected_points(n_clicks, selectedData, fig):
    if selectedData is not None:
        indices = [point['pointIndex'] for point in selectedData['points']]
        valid_indices = [index for index in indices if index >= 0 and index < len(df)]
        if len(valid_indices) > 0:
            df.drop(valid_indices, inplace=True)
            df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # <-- reset dataframe indices
            new_fig = go.Figure(
                data=[go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], mode='markers')],
                layout=layout)
            return new_fig
    return fig
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. You are right, the solution was to reset the dataframe index.

Comment: @HenriqueSchinaider It seems you've received the help you needed. If that is the case, please consider marking this suggestion as the accepted answer.